# I am not able to make a GET request in AXIOS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

Why I am getting this error CORS policy. I am on `localhost:3000` and backend is at `localhost:5000` I am getting data from backend server by making GET request to `localhost:5000/api/users`.

**userAction.js**

```
import { FETCH_USERS } from './types';
import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchUsers = () => dispatch => {
    axios.get(`localhost:5000/api/users`)
    .then( users => 
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_USERS,
            payload: users
        })
    )
    .catch( error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

**userReducer.js:**

```
import { FETCH_USERS } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    items: []
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_USERS:
            return {
                ...state,
                items: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Now I am making GET req to `localhost:5000/api/users` and I am on client `localhost:3000` I have added following code in `server.js` but still showing the same error.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: If you are using `express` then I would recommend you using `cors` middleware https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I met this problem last month, here is what i did to resolve. Try this for backend accpet cross domain (my backend is nodejs):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

//to allow cross domain requests to send cookie information.
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

// origin can not be '*' when crendentials are enabled. so need to set it to the request origin
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',  req.headers.origin);

// list of methods that are supported by the server
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');

res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept, X-XSRF-TOKEN');

    next();
});
```

// And settop axios default like this. I use React for client

```
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000/',
    withCredentials: true,
});

axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form- 
urlencoded';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.crossDomain = true;

export default instance;
```

Comment: Where should I setup axios instance ? and when making axios.get() request will anything change ? I mean while my userAction..js code change ?

Comment: here is my settup for axios instance. After you settup, each time you call axios. Instead `import axios from 'axios'`. your impport now is `import axios from '../path_to_axiso_instance_file.js'`  https://github.com/dangminhtruong/havana_client/tree/master/src

Comment: So in entire project wherever I use import axios I should replace it with import axios from '../path_to_axiso_instance_file.js' am I right ?

Comment: Yep. That what i do ^^

Comment: Getting error 404 why so ? Should the base url be localhost:5000/api/users ? I am making GET request to api/users to get all users

Comment: No. your request call now is axios.get('/api/users')

Comment: Will it work for GET request ? I am not able to get the data by making GET request check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53113878/not-able-to-fetch-data-from-axios-get-request

Comment: Here is my get data from get request https://github.com/dangminhtruong/havana_client/blob/master/src/components/pages/blog/index.js hope this help ^^

Answer (score 2):

In your `"package.json"` you can add a proxy to the server.
Just one line:

> "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily connect frontend (react) with backend(node-express) and solve CORS issues by adding `proxy` like so:

Inside `package.json` add the `proxy` property with the backend url:

`proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `express` server then use `cors` middleware. It's easy to use and manage CROS requests using this middleware.

[Node.js CORS middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable cors in your project.

Try this:

1. npm install cors --save
2. In your server.js

   ```
   const cors =require('cors')
   const express = require('express')
   const app = express()
   app.use(cors()) // app is your express object
   ```